# Missing Operand Error in Windows Batch

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

```
FOR /L %%i in (1,1,100) DO (
SET /A modder=%%i %% 3
SET /A result=%modder%+5
SET /A total=%total%+%result%
)
SET /A final=%total%/100
ECHO The average of (1 to 100 mod 3) +5 is: %total% >> results.txt
```

I'm new to scripting with Windows Batch, but I'm stuck here and can't figure anything out. I need to go through this for loop and calculate each number from 1 to 100 with mod 3 and then add 5 to it. (1 to 100 mod 3) + 5. After that, I need to append the final result into a results.txt file.

No matter what I do or change, the program either crashes instantly or I'll get a "Missing Operand" message 100 times. I can't tell where I've made a mistake and how to fix it. If someone could offer a hand, I would really appreciate that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) or you can just remove the `%`-es in the loop (works only with `set /a`):

```
@echo off
FOR /L %%i in (1,1,100) DO (
 SET /A modder=%%i %% 3
 SET /A result=modder+5
 SET /A total=total+result
)
SET /A final=%total%/100
ECHO The average of (1 to 100 mod 3) +5 is: %total%
```

Comment: Thanks so much! A very simple fix, but definitely helped.